# Throttling with HAProxy by IP

Tags: haproxy

We use HAProxy for load balancing on our site.

The site is highly dependent on cached data; when we take the site down for maintenance, most of those caches become stale. When we turn the site back on, and users start hitting the site again, we end up with a stampede; hundreds of users requesting that cached be regenerated.

While we've worked to mitigate this in several way (other stampede prevention techniques, warm-up scripts), we also think it would be helpful to throttle the number of users who can reach our site. However, a single page load is composed of multiple separate requests, so we don't want to just throttle number of connections; rather, we'd like to throttle the number of unique IP addresses that can make requests. What we are trying to do is similar to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/245867/how-to-rate-limit-concurrent-sessions-with-nginx-or-haproxy?rq=1), but I'm hoping that 5 years later, there may be a better solution.

Is there any way to do this sort of IP-based throttling with HAProxy?